# How to combine rows with the same timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine all rows of a dataframe that have the same time stamp into a single row. The df is 5k by 20.

```
             A      B      ...
 timestamp
    11:00    NaN    10     ...
    11:00    5      NaN    ...
    12:00    15     20     ...
    ...      ...    ...
```

group the 2 11:00 rows as follows

```
             A      B        ...
timestamp
    11:00    5      10       ...
    12:00    15     20       ...
    ...      ...    ...
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have tried

```
df.groupby( df.index ).sum()
```

Comment: What if they had both A and B columns filled?

Comment: You're asking if the NaN's in the above were values instead? In my case,  for each unique time stamp (the 2 rows of 11:00 in the above ex.) there will only be 1 value per column. I had initially tried a group by index and sum but this left me with all NaNs.

Comment: Post the code you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You could `melt` ('unpivot') the DataFrame to convert it from wide form to long form, remove the null values, then aggregate via `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['11:00','11:00','12:00'],
               'A' : [None,5,15],
               'B' : [10,None,20]
              })

    A   B   timestamp
0   NaN 10  11:00
1   5   NaN 11:00
2   15  20  12:00

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'timestamp') # specify the value_vars if needed

    timestamp   variable    value
0   11:00       A           NaN
1   11:00       A           5
2   12:00       A           15
3   11:00       B           10
4   11:00       B           NaN
5   12:00       B           20

df2.dropna(inplace=True)
df3 = df2.groupby(['timestamp', 'variable']).sum()

                        value
timestamp   variable    
11:00       A           5
            B           10
12:00       A           15
            B           20

df3.unstack()

            value
variable    A   B
timestamp       
11:00       5   10
12:00       15  20
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` after replacing the `NaN` values with 0's.

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
>>> df.resample('60Min', how='sum')
                      A   B
2015-05-28 11:00:00   5  10
2015-05-28 12:00:00  15  20
```

More examples can be found in the [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/faq.html#resampling-with-timestamps-and-periods).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sum a number and a NaN in python. You probably need to use .aggregate() :)

Comment: yeah, i've been messing around with aggregate also but I can't seem to figure it out.